# How to swap array values and generate a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, reverse

I have an array which is a set of coordinates, and I want to swap them, and generate a new array.

I want to swap only the regions entries:

```
var Regions = [
  {"group": "region_01",
  "coords": [
    [3110, 2323],
    [3119, 2344],
    [3117, 2385],
    [3110, 2417],
    [3110, 2323]
  ]}]
```

So it should be like this:

```
var Regions = [
  {"group": "region_01",
  "coords": [
    [2323, 3110],
    [2344, 3119],
    [2385, 3117],
    [2417, 3110],
    [2323, 3110]
  ]}]
```

The reverse method doesn't work in this type of array right? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Did you try anything? SO is about helping, not doing it for you.

Comment: I tried reverse, but it reversed the entire array, I want to swap the values only. I am asking for help, as I said I tried reverse only... If you don't want to help no need to comment here...

Comment: 20K rep suggests I do want to help, and frequently do. I'm merely pointing out that posters are expected to show an effort, rather than the disrespect of basically saying "please do this task for me".

Comment: @Utkanos Good that you have a lot of rep and help people. I didn't asked anything complicated for people that knows javascript. I didn't asked for people to write a complex function or anything else. It was a simple reverse method, which for me who are learning how arrays work, and have difficulties with it could be hard, and for experts in javascript could be very easy. Before coming here I tried a lot of things based on other answers, but coudn't find a way to do what I wanted. Before I ask anything here I try a lot to solve the problem on my own. But I expect help and not criticize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `reverse` to modify the original array.

```js
var Regions = [
  {"group": "region_01",
  "coords": [
    [3110, 2323],
    [3119, 2344],
    [3117, 2385],
    [3110, 2417],
    [3110, 2323]
  ]}];
  
Regions.forEach((r) => r.coords.forEach(c => c.reverse()));

console.log(Regions);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you don't want to use the function `reverse()`, you can use the function `map` to make the swap.

```js
var Regions = [
  {"group": "region_01",
  "coords": [
    [3110, 2323],
    [3119, 2344],
    [3117, 2385],
    [3110, 2417],
    [3110, 2323]
  ]}];
  
Regions.forEach((r) => r.coords = r.coords.map(([left, right]) => [right, left]));

console.log(Regions);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Good options. I didn't knew that the map function could do this too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) calls to reverse the sub arrays in place:

```js
const Regions = [{"group":"region_01","coords":[[2323,3110],[2344,3119],[2385,3117],[2417,3110],[2323,3110]]}];
  
Regions.forEach(({ coords }) => 
  coords.forEach((arr) => arr.reverse())
);

console.log(Regions);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Regions = {
  group: "region_01",
  coords: [
    [3110, 2323],
    [3119, 2344],
    [3117, 2385],
    [3110, 2417],
    [3110, 2323]
  ]
}

for (var i = 0, len = Regions.coords.length; i < len; i++) {
  var coord = Regions.coords[i];
  coord[1] = [coord[0], coord[0] = coord[1]][0];
}
```